# can we store multiple data entries in database corresponding only one primary key/sequence id?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

Is it possible to insert multiple data entries in database corresponding to one id.?
i want to insert data something like below:

```
   Seq_id    Name            Value

    1.       Bill.billNo     1234
             Bill.date       25/07/2014
             Person.fname     abc
             Person.lname     xyz

    2.       Bill.billNo     1220
             Bill.date       11/07/2014
             Person.fname     def
             Person.lname     ghy
```

Comment: Isn't the idea of having a primary key so that each value must be unique? Maybe I'm not getting what you want to achieve.

Comment: u can see the table format above. can we design db table this way?

Comment: i mean i want to map one object and all its attributes to one pk

Comment: You can create a spanning primary key, such as `(id, prop)` and so `(1, 'billno'), (2, 'date')`, etc.

Comment: can u elaborate more on this? m still nt getting how do we do this?

Comment: Just [Google it](https://www.google.com.sg/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mysql%20composite%20primary%20key).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the table as this:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable (
    seq_id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    value VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (seq_id, name)
);
```

The table contents would then be:

```
Seq_id    Name            Value

1        Bill.billNo     1234
1        Bill.date       25/07/2014
1        Person.fname     abc
1        Person.lname     xyz

2        Bill.billNo     1220
2        Bill.date       11/07/2014
2        Person.fname     def
2        Person.lname     ghy
```

If you want the `seq_id` to auto-increment separately for each name, it should be:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable (
    seq_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    value VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (name, seq_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

You have to reorder the columns in the `PRIMARY KEY` clause, because the auto-increment column must be the secondary column in the key. And you must use `MyISAM`, because secondary column auto-increment is not available in `InnoDB`.

Make sure that when you add rows, you add all the names for a particular `seq_id` at the same time. Otherwise, when it increments them automatically, they'll get out of sync between the names.

Comment: this seems fine.. using composite key.. i think this is the only solution to achieve this. thanks :)

Comment: i want seq_id to be auto incremented.. how can i achieve that? is it possible even if we use composite key?

Comment: See the description of auto increment of secondary columns in a composite key here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: I still dont get it.. can u plz tell me how can i achieve it in my case. my case is bit different i feel

Comment: Seems like you need to ask a new question so I can post a new answer.

Comment: could u post answer here itself?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea, I have never used PostGreSql. Doesn't it have documentation that you can read?